# How to get help for cURL in Windows

Tags: windows, powershell, http, curl

How can I get help for cURL command in Windows 10?
Run with params `help curl` `--help`, `/?` don't work.

The same is with master command `Invoke-WebRequest

```
Alias           curl -> Invoke-WebRequest
```

Comment: In PowerShell `curl` is only an alias for `Invoke-WebRequest` . See the help with:  `Get-Help Invoke-WebRequest`... Can you elaborate on what exactly is not working?

Comment: `curl -?` works as well (any native powershell command will respond with it's corresponding help page with you add `-?` to the end)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **Inside PowerShell, only `-` is recognized** as the parameter name (option) prefix sigil - not also `/`

  - The **[PowerShell *CLI*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh)** (`powershell.exe` for Windows PowerShell, `pwsh` for PowerShell [Core] 6+), by contrast, ***alternatively* accepts `/`**<sup>[1]</sup>; e.g.: `pwsh /?`
- **To invoke help for a PowerShell command**<sup>[2]</sup>:

  - **Pass `-?` as a parameter** for a brief summary - this works with both full command names (`Invoke-WebRequest -?`) and aliases (`curl -?`)<sup>[3]</sup>.
  - **Pass the command name to [`Get-Help`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-help)** to control the level of detail or extract relevant information selectively; e.g.:

    - `Get-Help Invoke-WebRequest` - same as: `Invoke-WebRequest -?`
    - `Get-Help Invoke-WebRequest -Detailed` - more details; there's also `-Full`
    - `Get-Help Invoke-WebRequest -Examples` - example commands
    - `Get-Help Invoke-WebRequest -Parameter Uri` - help for a given parameter

There's also a built-in `help` *function*, which is a wrapper around the `Get-Help` cmdlet that provides automatic output paging to make reading multi-page content easier.

---

<sup>[1] However, now that PowerShell is *cross-platform*, it's best to stick with `-`, given that `/` is used as the separator in file-system paths on Unix-like platforms.</sup>

<sup>[2] If you're calling an *external program*, e.g. `git`, you'll need to honor *its* convention for invoking help, such as

`git --help`.</sup>

<sup>[3] Note that in PowerShell [Core] 6+, `curl` isn't a built-in alias anymore, but another one - constructed based on PowerShell's naming conventions - still exists: `iwr`.</sup>